# Filling gaps by repeating a character

Tags: xetex, tex-core

I want to create a macro like `\mymacro` that has four arguments; first and fourth arguments are any letters, second argument is a character and the third argument is a length. When I say

```
\mymacro{م}
{ـ} % this is the Kashida
{100pt}
{ن}
```

I want as many Kashidas as possible to fill that 100pt length completely so that there is no white space. This will produce something like `مــــــــــــــــــــــن`.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ExternalLocation,Scale=3]{amiri-regular}
\begin{document}
مــــــــــــــــــــــن
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** I already tried David's solution myself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ExternalLocation,Scale=3,Script=Arabic]{amiri-regular}
\usepackage{bidi}
\setRTL
\chardef\myzwj="200D
\newcommand\mymacro[4]{\makebox[#3]{#1\myzwj\leaders\hbox{#2}\hfill\myzwj#4}}
\begin{document}
مــــــــــــــــــــــن

\mymacro{م}
{ـ} % this is the Kashida
{100pt}
{ن}

\end{document}
```

But I get some space in between (this is something I need to avoid). See the following image:

[image]

To answer Heiko's question:

**If the space is not an integer multiple of a base unit, where does the unoccupied space go?**

The macro should be smart enough to calculate how many Kashida's can go in 100pt. Say in 100pt you can have 15.5 Kashidas, the macro should put 15.5 Kashidas to fill that 100pt length completely (no white space at all).

Comment: If the space is not an integer multiple of a base unit, where does the unoccupied space go?

Comment: As @HeikoOberdiek comments on my answer, your ــــــ sequence has been ligatured in clumps of 4 (I think) producing a wavy line, is that needed (in which case you would want to \leaders in groups of 4, or is it supposed to make _one_ arc?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: I have updated the question and tried to answer your question.

Comment: does the `100pt` include the width of the letters at the extremities?

Comment: @jfbu: No, only the length that you want to fill with Kashida.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It is supposed to be one but I guess with Amiri, it is the font issue here.

Comment: When I measure the width of a box with `N` Kashidas I obtain something about `50%` larger than `N` times the width of a single Kashida. I suspect this is obvious to people who know what a Kashida is!

Comment: @jfbu yes as noted in the comments it's liguturing in clumps, just as if you go `---------` if the font has a `--` ligature but not `---` then it'll clump in pairs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Or possibly with `\beginL` etc added to force direction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ExternalLocation,Scale=3]{amiri-regular}
\newcommand\mymacro[4]{\makebox[#3]{#1\leaders\hbox{#2}\hfill#4}}
\begin{document}
مــــــــــــــــــــــن

\mymacro{م}
{ـ} % this is the Kashida
{100pt}
{ن}

\end{document}
```

---

adding some overprinting to account for a non integer number of filler characters, and a bit of negative space

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ExternalLocation,Scale=3]{amiri-regular}
\newcommand\mymacro[4]{#4\kern-1pt\rlap{#2}%
                       \makebox[#3]{\leaders\hbox{#2}\hfill}%
                       \llap{#2}\kern-1pt#1}
\begin{document}
مــــــــــــــــــــــن

\mymacro{م}
{ـ} % this is the Kashida
{100pt}
{ن}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unhappily `\leader` and friends can't be used, because that separates the glyphs from each other. The result is quite a straight line. But a closer look reveals a little more than five larger arcs in the long line of the question. An arc is formed by four characters (ligature? I can't copy and paste it).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek surely it's either leaders or going into the font and setting up some kind of arbitrary length ligature sequence?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Please see my edited question. Thanks

Comment: @VafaKhalighi updated:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Perfect. Is that `1pt` negative kern done by trial and error or there are some reasons behind it?

Comment: @VafaKhalighi trial and error, aslo I think you were getting more suitable glyphs for the end characters with stubs that join with the filler, when I tried it they had vertical tails so I just guessed some backspacing, but you understand that part a lot better than me so can probably take it from there:-)

Comment: if one obtains a straight line in the end why not simply a `\rule`?

Comment: @jfbu where's the fun in that:-) (and this way the font gets to choose the width) just like `--` isn't a rule.

Comment: @jfbu: Because the Kashida is not straight in all fonts; in some cursive Persian typography styles like Nastaligh (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasta%CA%BFl%C4%ABq_script).

Answer (score 17):

This answer provides the line by scaling the line character. A closer look at the character bounding box reveals, that there is some slanted part sticking to the left and right. Scaling would also alter the angle of the slanted part.
Therefore the implementation constructs the line with three parts:

- begin part by clipping the rest of the glyph
- scaled main middle part of the glyph
- end part by clipping the rest of the glyph

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ExternalLocation,Scale=3]{amiri-regular}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}

\newcommand*{\mymacro}[4]{%
  \leavevmode
  #1%
  \llap{\clipbox{-1ex 0pt {\width} 0pt}{#2}}%
  \resizebox{#3}{\height}{\clipbox{0pt}{#2}}%
  \rlap{\clipbox{{\width} 0pt -1ex 0pt}{#2}}%
  #4%
}

\begin{document}

% show bounding box:
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}
\scalebox{4}{\fbox{ـ}}

\medskip

مــــــــــــــــــــــن

\mymacro{م}{ـ}{100pt}{ن}

\mymacro{م}{ـ}{200pt}{ن}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result straight]

### Variation with slightly scaled wavy line

The next example adds a line glyph at a time until the length is smaller or equal the required length. Then the line is scaled to the required length.

Since the length is not a linear function of the number of glyphs, the example adds one glyph at a time and tests the length.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ExternalLocation,Scale=3]{amiri-regular}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mymacro}[4]{%
  \leavevmode
  #1%
  \ifdim#3>\z@ % 0pt
    \begingroup
      \def\glyphline{#2}%
      \settowidth{\dimen@}{\glyphline}%
      \let\next@glyphline\glyphline
      \@whiledim#3>\dimen@\do{%
        \let\glyphline\next@glyphline
        \expandafter
        \def\expandafter\next@glyphline\expandafter{\glyphline#2}%
        \settowidth{\dimen@}{\next@glyphline}%
      }%
      \llap{\clipbox{-1ex 0pt {\width} 0pt}{\glyphline}}%
      \resizebox{#3}{\height}{\clipbox{0pt}{\glyphline}}%
      \rlap{\clipbox{{\width} 0pt -1ex 0pt}{\glyphline}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi
  #4%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

مــــــــــــــــــــــن

\mymacro{م}{ـ}{50pt}{ن}

\mymacro{م}{ـ}{100pt}{ن}

\mymacro{م}{ـ}{150pt}{ن}

\mymacro{م}{ـ}{200pt}{ن}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result wavy]

Because of the scaling, the length of a wave vary a little among macro invocations with different line lengths.

Comment: This is super. This provides better quality than pasting the character `n` times. I do not know if I can put some bounty for this question; if I can, then I will give you 100 bounties. Thanks again.

Comment: By the way, if you delete all your `\beginR`, `\endR`, `\beginL`, and `\endL` and put `\usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}` after `\usepackage{trimclip}`, then your example works fine. I patched `trimclip` xetex driver few months ago in `bidi` package.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi Thanks, I have updated the examples using `\usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}`.